# Aligning Form in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-designer

I am trying to add functionality to a form in Visual Studio 2005 that extends the form to the left.  However,  I am unable to figure out how to change the top and left alignment of he form in the form designer.  There has to be a way to change the alignment of a form in the designer, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you wish to extend the form (in the designer) to the left in order to make space for new controls, I don't believe you can do it - you need to drag out the right side of the frame, then select all the other controls (just drag around them all with the selector tool) and then drag them to the right (you can also move them with right arrow key to ensure they stay at the same Y position).

Comment: What I need is space in the editor to the left of the Form.  it is not about space for new controls on the form, but a control that will open on the left of the form.